# Error message with the RMySQL package

Tags: r, rmysql

Windows 10
R v 3.3.2
Package "RMySQL"
When I want to access the fields of a table in a data base with this command:

```
> dbListFields(hg19,"affyU133PLus2")
```

I get this information :

> Error in .local(conn, statement, ...) :    could not run statement:
>   Table 'hg19.affyU133PLus2' doesn't exist

but this Table exist:

> allTables[1:19]
>
> [1] "HInv"                      "HInvGeneMrna"               [3]
>   "acembly"                   "acemblyClass"               [5]
>   "acemblyPep"                "affyCytoScan"               [7]
>   "affyExonProbeAmbiguous"    "affyExonProbeCore"          [9]
>   "affyExonProbeExtended"     "affyExonProbeFree"         [11]
>   "affyExonProbeFull"         "affyExonProbesetAmbiguous" [13]
>   "affyExonProbesetCore"      "affyExonProbesetExtended"  [15]
>   "affyExonProbesetFree"      "affyExonProbesetFull"      [17]
>   "affyGnf1h"                 "affyU133"                  [19]
>   "affyU133Plus2"

Comment: Maybe case matters? Try "affyU133Plus2" (the L should be l).

Comment: it was that,, Thank you a lot @Joshua I think than that iI better delete this question or not what you think?

Comment: It will likely be closed as a "simple typographical error", so I'd probably delete it.